# Incorrect syntax near '-' no Insert

Tags: sql, vb.net

Desenvolvi uma aplicação para registo de Clientes "Transportes" ligada a uma base de dados "MDF", ao tentar salvar para a base de dados dá o erro:

> "Incorrect syntax near '-'"

Já tentei de tudo, alterei os códigos, mudei varias coisas mas o erro prevalece.

Codigos:

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim ct As String = "select id from Clientes where id='" & IdTextBox.Text & "'"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(ct)
        cmd.Connection = con
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If rdr.Read() Then
            MessageBox.Show("Id ja existe", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
            IdTextBox.Text = ""
            IdTextBox.Focus()
            If (rdr IsNot Nothing) Then
                rdr.Close()
            End If
            Return
        End If

        con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        con.Open()

        Dim cb As String = "insert into Clientes(id, nome, cidade, matricula, marca, lotacao, partida, chegada, capacidade, estado, Tipo-Licenca, Licenca-emissao, licenca-expira, seguros-emissao, seguros-expira, ficha-emissao, ficha-expira, data-registado) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17,@d18)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cb)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", IdTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", NomeTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", CidadeComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", MatriculaTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", MarcaComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", LotacaoComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", PartidaComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8", ChegadaComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9", CapacidadeComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10", EstadoComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11", Tipo_LicencaComboBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d12", Licenca_emissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d13", Licenca_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d14", Seguros_EmissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d15", Seguros_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d16", Ficha_EmissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d17", Ficha_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d18", Now)
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente registado com sucesso", "Cliente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try
End Sub
```

Nota: O form Clientes tem ComboBox's que puxam dados de outras tabelas:
Exemplo: O ComboBox 'CapacidadeComboBox' puxa os dados da tabela 'Capacidade'

Comment: Este erro ocorre quando vc faz a pesquisa?

Comment: Julgo que o problema está em se usar o `-` no nome dos campos Tipo-Licenca, Licenca-emissao, etc. Tente colocá-los entre pelicas: `'Tipo-Licenca'`.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho não ao tentar salvar os dados na base de dados

Comment: Mesmo que não seja esse o problema sugiro que utilize TipoLicenca em vez de Tipo-Licenca ou Tipo_Licenca.

Comment: @ramaral coloquei, e o erro mudou para: Incorrect syntax near 'Tipo-Licenca'

Agora deu para perceber que realmente esta nos '-'

Comment: @ramaral agradecido, encontrei a solução...

[Tipo-Licenca]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
Try
    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()
    Dim ct As String = "select id from Clientes where id='" & IdTextBox.Text & "'"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(ct)
    cmd.Connection = con
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If rdr.Read() Then
        MessageBox.Show("Id ja existe", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
        IdTextBox.Text = ""
        IdTextBox.Focus()
        If (rdr IsNot Nothing) Then
            rdr.Close()
        End If
        Return
    End If

    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    con.Open()

    Dim cb As String = "insert into Clientes(id, nome, cidade, matricula, marca, lotacao, partida, chegada, capacidade, estado, [Tipo-Licenca], [Licenca-emissao], [licenca-expira], [seguros-emissao], [seguros-expira], [ficha-emissao], [ficha-expira], [data-registado]) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@d13,@d14,@d15,@d16,@d17,@d18)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cb)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", IdTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", NomeTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", CidadeComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", MatriculaTextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", MarcaComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6", LotacaoComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7", PartidaComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8", ChegadaComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9", CapacidadeComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10", EstadoComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11", Tipo_LicencaComboBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d12", Licenca_emissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d13", Licenca_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d14", Seguros_EmissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d15", Seguros_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d16", Ficha_EmissaoDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d17", Ficha_ExpiraDateTimePicker.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d18", Now)
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
    con.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Cliente registado com sucesso", "Cliente", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    btnSave.Enabled = False
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: Fez bem em postar a solução. No entanto, em vez de colocar todo esse código, sugiro que apenas explique a razão do problema e como resolvê-lo. Da forma como está fica complicado perceber a solução.